# How can I override val inside of method?

Tags: scala

I have scala trait something like this:

```
trait A {
 def foo()

 val val1:Set[Set1]
}
```

I have a class which extends this trait. Something like this:

```
class B extends A {

 override val val1 = //Something
 override def foo() {
   //change Something here 
 } 
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: best to avoid mutability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance has nothing to do with "changing" vals. First of all, you can't reassing a val:

```
class B {
  val val1 = Set("Something")

  def foo(): Unit = {
    val1 = Set("Some other thing")  // reassigning val1; will not compile
  }
}
```

`val`s denote immutable variables, so you can't change what these variables contain.

However, you can change these variables insides if their type supports it. For example, if we make `val1` a mutable set and then attempt to modify this set in the method:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class B {
  val val1 = mutable.Set("Something")

  def foo(): Unit = {
    val1 += "Another thing"
  }
}
```

Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to change the value `val1` inside method `foo` that is how exactly you override the vals and defs.

You can override `defs` and `vals` with `vals`, but you cannot override `vals` with `defs`

```
trait A {
  val a:Int
}

class B extends A {
  def a = 5           //Compilation error
}
```

Comment: I did not mean change it with def. I would like change val inside of method. I think it is possible. But how?

Comment: `val`s are immutable unless you are using a mutable thing like mutable collection. You cannot change `val`s anyware. Use var instead.